# Does rifaximin (Xifaxin) treat irritable bowel syndrome?

Tags: medical-science

This article [5 Simple Steps to Cure IBS Without Drugs](http://drhyman.com/blog/2010/09/16/5-simple-steps-to-cure-ibs-without-drugs/)

> Get rid of the unwanted visitors in your small bowel. Ask your doctor to prescribe rifaximin (Xifaxin) and take two 200 mg tablets three times a day for seven to 10 days. This is often the best way to deal with the chronic bacterial overgrowth that causes bloating and irritable bowel syndrome.  You may also need an anti-fungal such as nystatin or fluconazole for two to four weeks.

Does taking two 200 mg rifaximin (Xifaxin) tablets three times a day for seven to 10 days helps to deal with chronic bacterial overgrowth?

Comment: Its [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rifaximin) (citing a study published in the New England Journal of Medicine) says it is. Are you skeptical of the results of this study? Incidentally, "Dr. Hyman" (or whoever runs the blog linked) should probably be aware that rifaximin is in fact a drug (as are antifungals).

Comment: Something to keep in mind:  IBS is a diagnosis of exclusion and thus very well might have multiple causes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

A quick search on Google Scholar found [several](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10620-007-9839-8#page-1) [relevant](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1004409) [studies](http://www.nature.com/ajg/journal/v101/n2/abs/ajg200665a.html).

A 2009 review of the research found:

> Rifaximin improved global symptoms in 33 – 92% of patients and eradicated SIBO in up to 84% of patients with IBS, with results sustained up to 10 weeks post-treatment. Rifaximin caused a lower number of adverse events compared with metronidazole or levofloxacin and may have a more favorable adverse event profile than systemic antibiotics, without clinically relevant antibiotic resistance.

Source: [Review of rifaximin as treatment for SIBO and IBS](http://informahealthcare.com/doi/abs/10.1517/13543780902780175)

*This is not a medical self-help site. See a doctor for personalised advice if you suffer from the symptoms of IBS (or any serious disease).*